# Where can I start creating a Windows application?

Tags: windows

I want to create an application to run on a Windows 7 PC with a touch screen that is a sort of toolbox with large icons optimized for touch screens.

I need it to include a file browser with a hard coded path. That way I can auto launch the application and they will be taken to the folder right away. I would also like a section where I can put "Useful Applications" shortcuts so that they do not have to go through the start menu or the desktop.

Can someone guide me where I can start learning how I can do this? I would most likely code in C#

Answer (score 0):

Get started with Windows Runtime apps. You can write a Windows Runtime app in a variety of languages, such as C# or C++ with XAML, C++ with DirectX, and JavaScript with HTML/CSS. Now you can easily create apps for Windows devices and Windows Phone from a single project.

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted